# Prove this expression approaches 0 as a limit (Real Analysis)

Tags: real-analysis, limits

Show that for any $A > 1$ and any integer $k\geq1$
$lim_{n\to\infty} {\frac{n^k}{A^n}}=0$

The hint given in the question is: write $A=1+\alpha; \alpha>0$ and use the binomial theorem to get an appropriate inequality, and deduce $\frac{A^n}{n^{k+1}}>C$ for some constant $C>0$ provided $n\geq N_0$ (for $n$ large enough). Then use it to conclude.

Comment: I think the hint provides a good way of going about this. Did you try applying the hint, and if so, where did you get stuck?

Comment: In simplifying/progressing the fraction where I have substituted 1+alpha and expanded (the denominator)

Comment: How familiar are you with the binomial theorem?

Comment: I can prove it and have dealt with expansions in the form of (1+x)^n where |x|<1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you might be stuck at a point in this approach that a lot of students stumble. You seem to know the binomial theorem well enough to write
$$A^n = (1 + \alpha)^n = \binom{n}{0} + \binom{n}{1} \alpha + \binom{n}{2} \alpha^2 + \ldots + \binom{n}{n} \alpha^n.$$
The next step, which some students miss, is to analyse the binomial terms further. Note that $\binom{n}{1} = n$, $\binom{n}{2} = \frac{1}{2}n(n - 1)$, $\binom{n}{3} = \frac{1}{6}n(n - 1)(n - 2)$. Basically, for a fixed $k$, we have, for $n \ge k$, $\binom{n}{k}$ is some polynomial of $n$, of degree $k$. Particularly,
$$\binom{n}{k} = \frac{n!}{k!(n - k)!} = \frac{1}{k!}n(n - 1)(n - 2) \ldots (n - k + 1).$$
So, if we consider the sequence for only $n > k$, and take only the first $k + 1$ terms of the binomial expansion, we get,
$$A^n \ge \binom{n}{0} + \binom{n}{1} \alpha + \binom{n}{2} \alpha^2 + \ldots + \binom{n}{k} \alpha^k,$$
in particular, $A^n$ is eventually larger than a polynomial of degree $k$, for any $k$. Let $p$ be this polynomial, and we see that, eventually
$$\frac{n^{k-1}}{A^n} \le \frac{n^{k-1}}{p(n)} = \frac{1}{p(n)/n^{k-1}}.$$
But, since $p(n)$ is of degree $k$, we know that $p(n)/n^{k-1}$ contains an $n$ term, and will approach $\infty$, making $\frac{n^{k-1}}{A^n} \to 0$.